# AngularJS $compile while using third party (jquery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs

I'm implementing angularjs on a site currently using jquery to load stuff. Content is loaded asynchronously and then appended to the DOM via jquery, not angularjs. So I have something like this:

```js
function loadContent () {
    $("#target").html("<my-directive></my-directive>");
}

var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "my-directive is loaded"
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <my-directive></my-directive>
    <button onclick="loadContent()">load content</button>
    <div id="target"></div>
</div>
```

So my question is, is it possible to use `$compile` via jquery? Is there even a way to achieve it?

I'm aware I should load data and try to manage everything with angular but for now it's impossible or I'll break all the old stuff. This is why I'm asking such a question.

**NOTE**: This is a simple example, in my real case I also have some controllers and other angular stuff in the loaded html.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it's a good idea to use angular in your ways.

You can do like this. Use `$http` or your own `service` to load data. And bind your directive's data via `=`.

But, we can use  `$compile` to achieve what you like:

```
$scope.loadContent = function () {
    var html = $compile("<my-directive></my-directive>")($scope);
    $("#target").append(html);
};
```

More details see http://jsfiddle.net/creeper/cyw9b2pk/

Comment: Yes, I'm sad I have to do such things but the whole site is built on top of jquery and I can't break everything for now.